# como valido que solo se introduzcan 11 números en un TextForm Field

Tags: formularios, flutter, validación, text

Este es el codigo que tengo:
ya valida la entrada de números solamente, solo me queda que sean solo 11 (es para un # carnet de identidad)

```dart
TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "CI",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left, validator: (text) {
                    final intNumber=int.tryParse(text!);
                  if (text == null || text.isEmpty ||   intNumber! <= 11) {
                    return 'Campo vacio o no es un número CI';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter> [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo de 2 formas:

1- Usando el `LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter`.

```dart
inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter> [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly, 
//Añades este
LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(11)
],
```

2- Usas la propiedad `maxLength` del `TextField`:

```dart
TextField(
  maxLength: 11,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    // Agregas esto para que no te aparezca el contador de caracteres
    counterText: ''
  ),
)
```